# How to launch Fuzzy Logic?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to launch the Fuzzy Logic addin in Excel, using VBA.

I have got the addin, and have used the macros recording tool to try and see how it is done.

However, the macros recording does not show the launch of the Fuzzy Logic or the setting of the parameters.

Any suggestions on how to launch the addin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Readme.docx file included with the add-in:

> Can I call Fuzzy Lookup from VB or C#?
>
> Programmatic access is not presently available.

The comments on [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/business_intelligence_labs/archive/2011/04/27/fuzzy-lookup-add-in-for-excel.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments) blog post seem to also indicate that this is not possible at this time.

The closest I can come is the following:

- Add the launch icon to the quick access toolbar
- Add VBA SendKeys "%5" (where 5 is the position of the icon in the quick access toolbar)
- The VBA should make sure that the Excel spreadsheet is displayed before using SendKeys (it won't work if you displaying the VBE)

Tabbing around on the Fuzzy Logic pane gets stuck about halfway through the controls.

In VBA, you can create a reference to the pane:

```
Dim cb as CommandBar
Set cb = Application.CommandBars("Fuzzy Lookup")
```

You can display the caption of the pane.

```
MsgBox cb.controls(1).caption
```

You can't modify the visible property of the CommandBar nor the CommandBarControl. For comparison, you can display the Selection Pane quite easily with the following:

```
Application.CommandBars("Selection").visible = true
```